# Explanation Request: Sorted Array Find Non-Repeating Element

Tags: arrays, search, binary-search

Following is the javascript code to find the element that doesn't repeat in a sorted array. I got this logic from a book. I am not able to understand why the mid % 2 if-else condition is being checked. Can some please explain the logic behind it?

```
    function findOnlyOnce(arr, low, high) {
    if (low > high) {
        return null;
    }
    if (low == high) {
        return arr[low];
    }

    var mid = Math.floor((high + low) / 2);

    if (mid % 2 == 0) {
        if (arr[mid] == arr[mid + 1]) {
            return findOnlyOnce(arr, mid + 2, high);
        } else {
            return findOnlyOnce(arr, low, mid);
        }
    } else {
        if (arr[mid] == arr[mid - 1]) {
            return findOnlyOnce(arr, mid + 1, high);
        } else {
            return findOnlyOnce(arr, low, mid - 1);
        }
    }
}

function findOnlyOnceHelper(arr) {
    return findOnlyOnce(arr, 0, arr.length);
}

console.log(findOnlyOnceHelper([1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

(mid % 2 == 0) is checking if the amount of numbers in array is odd or even.

Comment: I know that. I wanted to know what is the purpose of checking it. How does it help the logic.